# How to type variables defined in script setup for unit tests?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, unit-testing, vuejs3, vitest

I'm using a reactive state in my component, defined in `script setup`:

```
const state = reactive({
    hello: 'world'
})
```

It's accessible inside tests like so:

```
wrapper.vm.state.hello = 'mad-world'
```

unfortunately the `typescript check` doesn't seem to see the variable types in the `vm` and throws an error:

```
test/unit/components/price/my-component.test.ts:56:16 - error TS2339: Property 'state' does not exist on type 'MyComponent & { $: ComponentInternalInstance; $data: {}; $props: {}; $attrs: Data; $refs: Data; $slots: Readonly<InternalSlots>; ... 7 more ...; $watch<T extends string | ((...args: any) => any)>(source: T, cb: T extends (...args: any) => infer R ? (args_0: R, args_1: R) => any : (...args: any) => any, options?: Wat...'.

56     wrapper.vm.state.hello = 'mad-world'
```

type declaration:

```
export interface MyComponent extends ComponentPublicInstance {
    state: {
        hello: string
    }
}
```

used in test like so:

```
let wrapper: VueWrapper<MyComponent>

beforeEach(async () => {
    wrapper = mount({ ... }) as VueWrapper<MyComponent>
})
```

There seems to be a way to expose these variables from the `data` method of the vanilla `script` tag but not with `script setup`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your way of testing the inner implementation is not a good practice, you should focus only on the component public api (props, slots, emitted events ...). Anyway, to get types inference from component created with script setup syntax you should use the defineExpose macro as follows :

```html
<script setup lang="ts">

const state = reactive({
    hello: 'world'
})

defineExpose({
  state,
})
</script>
```